# Switching mode of my Huawei E3531

Tags: serial-port, gsm, at-command, huawei-mobile-services

I'm using Mac OS X. I bought this Huawei E3531 because I need to use it as a GSM modem trough AT commands to send SMS. Connection is fine and all works great, but I need to switch the mode so that it can works as a serial modem and I can connect to it trought the screen command

```
screen /dev/tty...
```

According to this post [Trying to use the AT command with an Huawei E3531](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29392102/trying-to-use-the-at-command-with-an-huawei-e3531) I'm trying to switch the mode. Problem is that it doesn't work.
Here I show you my moves.
First of all I need to find the vendor Id and the Product Id of this product so I launch the following command:

```
lsusb
```

I find this line very interessant:

> Bus 038 Device 003: ID 12d1:14dc Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. HUAWEI
>   Mobile

So, the vendor Id is 12d1 and the product id is 14dc.
Now I want to switch the mode by this command:

```
sudo usb_modeswitch -R -v 12d1 -p 14dc -W -M '55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000'
```

As result it gives me the following log:

```
MacBook-Pro-di-mac:usb-modeswitch-2.5.2 mac$ sudo ./usb_modeswitch -R -v 12d1 -p 14dc -W -M '55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000'
Password:
Take all parameters from the command line


 * usb_modeswitch: handle USB devices with multiple modes
 * Version 2.5.2 (C) Josua Dietze 2017
 * Based on libusb1/libusbx

 ! PLEASE REPORT NEW CONFIGURATIONS !

DefaultVendor=  0x12d1
DefaultProduct= 0x14dc
MessageContent="55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000"

Look for default devices ...
  found USB ID 12d1:14dc
   vendor ID matched
   product ID matched
  found USB ID 05ac:8213
  found USB ID 05ac:0237
  found USB ID 0a5c:4500
  found USB ID 05ac:8403
  found USB ID 05ac:8242
  found USB ID 05ac:8507
 Found devices in default mode (1)
Access device 003 on bus 038
Get the current device configuration ...
Current configuration number is 1
Use interface number 0
 with class 2
Error: can't use storage command in MessageContent with interface 0; interface class is 2, expected 8. Abort
```

How can I resolve this error? I searched also in other forum, websites and so on, but didn't find a satisfied solution.
Thank you

Comment: I "resolved" using this procedure and not AT commands anymore:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016641/sending-and-receiving-sms-by-command-line-with-huawei-e3131-and-hilink-on-a-debi